# Она нашла женщину ухаживать за бабушкой

Tags: синтаксис

В анализируемом тексте встречается такое предложение:

*Она нашла женщину ухаживать за бабушкой.*

Скажите, оно звучит правильно для Вас? Я думала, что если субъекты разные, надо использовать **чтобы**. 
*Она нашла женщину, чтобы та ухаживала за бабушкой.*

Еще вопрос: можно сказать, что предикат имеет целевой оттенок?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Она нашла женщину (для чего? с какой целью) ухаживать за бабушкой.

Это обстоятельство цели, выраженное инфинитивом.

Сравнить: Она нашла женщину для ухода за бабушкой.

Здесь **двойные связи**: нашла кого? и нашла зачем? Получается: женщина для ухода за бабушкой.

**Другие конструкции с инфинитивом**: 1) объектные инфинитив: приказал стрелять; 2) обстоятельство цели (с глаголами движения и положения): поехал встречать, приехал погостить, остался ночевать; 3) несогласованное определение: решение уехать.

Примечание. Скорее всего, такие грамматические конструкции характерны для разговорной речи: Завел собаку охранять участок. Купил лейку поливать цветы.