# Я убедил ее, чтобы она прилетела в Вашингтон.

Tags: синтаксис

> Я убедил ее, чтобы она прилетела в Вашингтон.

Если я правильно понимаю, это изъяснительное придаточное с оттенком цели. 
Я читала что если субъекты одинаковые в обеих частях предложений можно использовать инфинитив. 
Правильно так?

> Я убедил ее прилететь в Вашингтон.

Вы как носители языка какую версию предпочли бы?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

1) **В словаре разрешены обе формы**:

УБЕДИТЬ,  2. (обычно с инф. или союзом чтобы). **Уговаривая, склонить к чему-л., заставить сделать что-л.** Надо у. больного обследоваться. Убеди сына отказаться от приглашения. Ты хочешь у. меня, чтобы я принял участие в конференции?

2) Предпочтительным является вариант  **с объектным инфинитивом**: Я убедил ее (в чём?) прилететь в Вашингтон.

**3) Рассмотрим словарный вариант:** Ты хочешь убедить меня, чтобы я принял участие в конференции? Попробуем использовать объектный инфинитив:Ты хочешь **убедить** меня **принять** участие в конференции? Мы видим, что  этом случае **два инфинитива нежелательны**, так как понимание смысла предложения затрудняется.

4) **Почему разрешенная форма "убедил, чтобы" нам кажется в чем-то некорректной?**

Дело в том, что глагол "убедить" не является только речевым глаголом, как в изъяснительном предложении "сказал, чтобы", поэтому данное предложение – это нечто среднее между изъяснительным и местоименным дополнительным, для которого требуется **обязательное указательное слово В ТОМ**: Я убедил ее (в том), чтобы она прилетела в Вашингтон.

Comment: Боюсь, что добавление "в том" не спасает конструкцию с имеющимся "чтобы" ("в том, что ей следует..." - работает) при глаголах "убедить", "попросить" и пр. С глаголом "сказать(, чтобы она)" всё нормально (в сочетании с инфинитивом). Пример из словаря (п.1) по форме далёк от рассматриваемого предложения.

Comment: Sibylla, можно Вам задать вопросы:
а) посмотрите, пожалуиста, ответ использователя Мимоходов. Цитата: "Это и есть придаточное цели." Это правда? 
b) если сравнить два предл. (1) Он хочет, чтобы я пошел на концерт певицы ХY. и (2) Он захотел пойти на концерт, чтобы певица ХY дала ему автограф. 1 - это изъяснительное и 2 - целевое? Так правильно? 
с) "Я позабочусь о том, чтобы тебе никто не мешал." В моих глазах "чтобы тебе никто не мешал" это цель заботы и в моем языке это целевое СПП. А в русском наверно изъяснительное, так? Большое спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Я убедил ее, чтобы она прилетела в Вашингтон. Это не придаточное цели,  мы не можем поставить вопрос "зачем".  Это предложение  - нечто среднее  между местоименным дополнительным и изъяснительным, в обоих случаях задается падежный вопрос (убедил в чем, а не убедил зачем). Здесь с помощью придаточного передается СОДЕРЖАНИЕ ситуации, а не цель действия. Сравнить: Я убедил ее в необходимости встречи, чтобы (для того чтобы)  она поскорее приехала в Вашингтон.  Это придаточное цели.

Comment: (1) Он хочет, чтобы я пошел на концерт певицы ХY. и (2) Он захотел пойти на концерт, чтобы певица ХY дала ему автограф. 1 - это изъяснительное и 2 - целевое? Так правильно?  Да, здесь всё правильно.   с) "Я позабочусь о том, чтобы тебе никто не мешал.  Это придаточное изъяснительное, раскрывающее тему.  Для проверки заменим простой союз ЧТОБЫ  на составной: Я позабочусь (о том), для того чтобы  тебе никто не мешал.

Comment: Это сделать не удается, значит,  это не придаточное цели.  Просто цель является ТЕМОЙ изъяснительной части. Именно поэтому нам кажется, что здесь присутствует "оттенок цели".

Comment: Большое спасибо!! =)

Answer (score 1):

Я бы предпочел второй вариант. Кстати, в Нацкорпусе не удалось найти ничего похожего на первый вариант, хотя на просторах интернета этот вариант встречается.

Comment: Не могли бы Вы сказать мне чем режет Ваш слух первое предложение? хочу сказать: что неестественно для норм русского языка в первом предложении?

Comment: Не считаю, что первый вариант нарушает нормы. Как по-другому сказать: "Я убедил ее, чтобы мы вместе забрали Гертруду из монастырской обители" (http://loveread.ec/read_book.php?id=47286&p=56)? В вашем примере мне просто не нравится неоправданное многословие.

Comment: "Я убедил её, что нам с ней нужно..."

Comment: @Alex_ander Смысл немного не тот. "Убедил сделать" - не то же, что "убедил, что нужно сделать". "Убедил ее, чтобы она сделала" = "убедил ее сделать", но для "убедил ее, чтобы мы сделали" нет полного аналога.

Comment: Это перевод некой иноязычной конструкции. А в русском тексте проверенного автора встречается такое? Понимаю, что здесь есть акцент на результативность убеждения (позже так и вышло), но не уверен, что в русском это хороший стиль. В момент убеждения речь всегда идёт о предмете убеждения, а не о его результативных последствиях.

Comment: @Alex_ander - (1) Убедил сделать - убедил, что нужно сделать, а также **породил решимость сделать это** , и возможно, что уже и результат есть. (2) Проверенного автора не нашел. Согласен, что не очень хороший стиль, но в живой речи применяется - это факт. И в книжках (не только в переводных). Может, надо принять?

Comment: Спасибо Вам за ответы! я стараюсь понять почему (если по правилу в 2 частях предложения разные субъекты надо использовать "чтобы" + л-форма; а субъекты не одинаковые в этих частях) русское ухо предпочитает инфинитив? там что-то  блокирует использование "чтобы" наверно?

Answer (score 1):

Вторая версия безупречна. В первой, помимо лишних слов, обращает на себя внимание зависимость действия, совершаемого с отдельно от него сформулированной целью, от самой цели: она одновременно является содержанием действия. Этого недостатка нет в таком предложении, где предпринятое действие носит законченный, самодостаточный характер:

> Я купил ей билет, чтобы она прилетела в Вашингтон.

Любопытно, что таких проблем не наблюдается с глаголами, вводящими косвенную речь, например, с глаголом "сказать" (после него вполне ожидаем оборот по первому варианту):

> Я сказал ей, чтобы она прилетела в Вашингтон.

А вот с глаголом "велеть" это уже не проходит, явно предпочтителен вариант:

> Я велел ей лететь в Вашингтон.

Comment: спасибо за ответ! извините, я не поняла часть "обращает на себя внимание зависимость действия, совершаемого с отдельно от него сформулированной целью, от самой цели: она одновременно является содержанием действия" =(

Comment: Я имею в виду, что первая часть фразы не имеет законченного смысла, а для раскрытия этого смысла (содержание действия -  **в чём** убедил) требуется иная связь со второй частью предложения (напр. "убедил её в том, что...") - не такая, как при указании цели действия.

Answer (score 1):

Вы правы: это придаточное изъяснительное. В таких случаях от главного слова можно задать падежный вопрос. Я убедил ее **(в чем?),** чтобы она прилетела в Вашингтон.

При глаголах волеизъявления **(просить,
приказать, советовать, рекомендовать, убеж­
дать, запрещать, требовать, велеть)** прида­
точное предложение с союзом **чтобы** может
заменяться конструкцией  **Отец посоветовал, чтобы сын посту­
пил на работу,— Отец посоветовал сыну по­
ступить на работу-,** **Я попросил, чтобы шофёр
остановил м а ш и н у . Я попросил шофера оста­новить машину.**

> При такой замене союз **чтобы** опускается,
>   личная форма глагола-сказуемого в придаточ­
>   ном предложении заменяется **инфинитивом,**
>   а подлежащее придаточного предложения ста­
>   новится объектом в дательном или винитель­
>   ном падеже. В этой конструкции действие
>   инфинитива относится **не к подлежащему,** а к
>   объекту: **Я просил шофёра остановить маши­ну — просил я, а остановит машину шофёр.**

Ср.: **Я убедил ее прилететь в Вашингтон - убедил я, а приедет она.**

Подробно об этом можете прочитать в статье 
**Л. 
А. Дерибас 
"Употребление  союзов
что
  и 
чтобы"**.

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, первое предложение постороено неверно.

УБЕДИТЬ можно КОГО и В ЧЁМ?, глагол УБЕДИТЬ всегда требует дополнения. В данном сложноподчинённом предложении  он требует указательного слова В ТОМ в главной части и местоименно-определительного придаточного с союзом ЧТО, относящегося к этому указательному слову, а не к глаголу:

***Я убедил её в том, что она должна прилететь в Вашингтон.***

Предложение ***Я убедил её прилететь*** как раз отвечает требованиям глагола: УБЕДИЛ (в чём?) ПРИЛЕТЕТЬ.

Так что второй вариант правильный.

Answer (score 0):

> Если я правильно понимаю, это изъяснительное придаточное с оттенком
>   цели.

Да. Но почему "с оттенком"? Это и есть придаточное цели.

Вот [здесь](http://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/747-235_pridatochnye_celi.html), например.

> Я читала что если субъекты одинаковые в обеих частях предложений можно
>   использовать инфинитив.

Не понял смысла высказывания. У вас-то - **разные субъекты действия** (я и она), инфинитив не проходит. Примеры же такого инфинитива есть по ссылке выше.

> Для того, чтобы войти в Пришвина, разговориться с ним, надо замедлить
>   течение своей души (Солоухин).
>
> Он употребил свое красноречие, дабы отвратить Акулину от её намерения
>   (Пушкин).
>
> Командир бригады принял решение прекратить преследование до рассвета,
>   с тем чтобы к утру подтянуть резервы (Шолохов).

Здесь субъект одинаков в обеих частях.

> Правильно так?
>       "Я убедил ее прилететь в Вашингтон."

Правильно, разумеется. Но это уже не придаточное цели, это вообще не придаточное. ))) Это обычное управление типа "вспомогательный (модальный) глагол плюс инфинитив глагола-действия". "Убедил" здесь выступает в роли модального глагола.

> Вы как носители языка какую версию предпочли бы?

Вторую. Но обоснование этого не в грамматике, о которой вы говорили, а в простоте построения. Как видно из обсуждения в других ответах, это далеко не всегда получается корректно, поэтому надо следить за адекватность передачи мысли в таком "коротком" варианте, зависит от взаимоотношений субъектов и объектов обоих глаголов. Использование же придаточного позволяет сформулировать любую мысль подобного типа без ограничений.

Кстати, вы эту ошибку делаете уже не в первый раз.
[Она нашла женщину ухаживать за бабушкой](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/424448/)

Comment: Извините, да, я понимаю что много раз спрашиваю подобные вопросы и хотя я много на эту тему читала мне до сих пор очень тяжело понять отличие между изъяснительными предложениями с "чтобы" и целевыми предложениями (потому что в моем языке они все целевые).

Comment: @Anonym Во-первых, не вижу причин для извинений. Вы спрашиваете - вам рассказывают. Ошибка была в том, что вы привязываете к грамматике то, что объясняется полностью или в основном стилистикой.   Во-вторых, не берите в голову, если русский для вас не родной, то вам эта разница и не потребуется. Но если хотите, давайте откроем специальную тему. Только предупредите, что у вас - РКИ (русский как иностранный) и расскажите, какой у вас родной.

Comment: А пока давайте так. Я не имею правильной методики преподавания таких вещей и не знаю, какой у вас родной. Поэтому экспромт. Разницы в грамматике почти нет. С ней и носители русского путаются основательно. Разница проявляется в семантике, в смысле. Я понимаю, вам объяснили, что придаточное цели обычно можно заменить  на инфинитив, но это абсолютное правило. И если оно не понятно, давайте по-другому. В придаточном изъяснительном весь смысл заключен в придаточной части. Без неё смысл непонятен.

Comment: В основной части ау такого предложения сказуемое - обычно модальный (или исполняющий роль модального) глагол (хочу, знаю и т.п)  "Я хочу, чтоб к штыку приравняли перо" Маяковский). Вот здесь еще примеры таких конструкций изъяснительного с "чтобы". http://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/295-slognopodchinennye-predlogeniya-s-pridatochnymi-izyasnitelnymi.html. Без второй, придаточной, части предложение почти не несет смысла, оно непонятно. Это придаточное ***изъяснительное***.

Comment: В отличие от него, конструкция с ***придаточным цели*** сама по себе вполне осмыслена в основной части, глагол-сказуемое в основной части, хотя зачастую и выполняет роль модального, сам по себе имеет смысловое значение, придаточная же часть только уточняет. Примкры я вам приводил по ссылке в тексте основного ответа. Но, повторюсь, эта разница действительно не всегда столь очевидно, могут быть спорные случаи. Но главное, она, эта разница, не критична для понимания и общения. Проблемы возникаю скорее из-за недостатка разговорной практики.

Comment: В вашем случае громоздкая конструкция показалась вам более правильной по сравнению с естественной, просто.