# Глагол "просить"

Tags: сказуемые

Два вопроса:

1. Скажите, пожалуйста, правильно я поняла:

> Он просил Бога дать ему мудрость.

Хотелось бы знать какое сказуемое здесь.
Согласно похожим примерам в интернете "просил" - простое глагольное сказуемое, "дать" - дополнение. Это так?

2. Теперь представьте, пожалуйста, что Вам надо перевести предложение, допустим "*He asked God to give him wisdom*."

Какую версию Вы предпочли бы?

> a) Он просил Бога, чтобы он дал ему мудрость.
>
> b) Он просил Бога дать ему мудрость.

Спасибо!

Comment: [Повтор похожего вопроса](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/432185/%d0%af-%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bb-%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%92%d0%b0%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bd)

Comment: @Серж: uff Вы правы, извините! у меня был даже маленький déjà vu когда составляла вопрос =) спасибо за статью (еще раз!!!) jajajajajajajajaja

Answer (score 3):

(1) Он просил, чтобы Бог дал ему мудрость. СПП с придаточным изъяснительным.
(2) Он просил Бога дать ему мудрость. Дополнение: просил о чём.

Смысл одинаковый, поэтому выбор формы зависит от стиля речи, распространенности текста.

Надо учитывать, что  выделительная способность придаточного больше, чем у дополнения, поэтому этот вариант (1) мне кажется более подходящим. Также в распространенном предложении удобнее использовать придаточное.

Дополнение лучше использовать в кратких предложениях разговорного характера.

Сравнить:

Он просил, чтобы я прислал ему повесть в Москву. Он и меня просил, чтобы я помог ему и там тоже.

Какой-то журналист просил дать ему интервью. Отец просил дать ему подумать.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь простое глагольное сказуемое(просил) и дополнение (дать).

При глаголах волеизъявления **(просить, приказать, советовать, рекомендовать, убеж­ дать, запрещать, требовать, велеть)** прида­ точное предложение с союзом чтобы может заменяться **конструкцией с инфинитивом.** **Отец посоветовал, чтобы сын посту­ пил на работу,— Отец посоветовал сыну по­ ступить на работу-, Я попросил, чтобы шофёр остановил м а ш и н у . Я попросил шофера оста­новить машину.**

При такой замене союз чтобы опускается, личная форма глагола-сказуемого в придаточ­ ном предложении заменяется инфинитивом, а подлежащее придаточного предложения ста­новится объектом в дательном или винитель­ ном падеже. В этой конструкции действие инфинитива относится не к подлежащему, а к объекту: Я просил шофёра остановить маши­ну — просил я, а остановит машину шофёр.

**Ср.: Я убедил ее прилететь в Вашингтон - убедил я, а приедет она.
Подробно об этом можете прочитать в статье Л. А. Дерибас "Употребление союзов что и чтобы".**

> Подробно об этом можете прочитать в статье Л. А. Дерибас "Употребление союзов что и чтобы".

Answer (score 1):

1. **Да**. Здесь "дать" логично считать дополнением, поскольку "просил" - самодостаточный смысловой глагол, на модальный или фазовый не похож, на связку - тем более. Поэтому "дать" - дополнение, выраженное инфинитивом.
2. С точки зрения грамматики и семантики эти **варианты полностью эквивалентны**. 
   Но а) длиннее и путанее (он/ему - тут что-то надо менять, это же о разных субъектах).

Кстати, вы интересную мысль подбросили. Прямой "перевод" грамматики с английского (если он в принципе допустим) будет чаше всего и самым правильным. Это приятное свойство английского языка в краткости и хорошей формализованности всем конструкций. Обычно такие конструкции всегда ценятся и в других языках. Обратное, разумеется, неверно. Оба факта хорошо видны при машинном переводе в обе стороны.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Рада видеть Вас здесь снова! =)